# LwIP buffer management for sending UDP messages

Tags: udp, lwip

My embedded application uses the LwIP library to send UDP messages of varying lengths, depending on the contents.

Right now I'm calling pbuf_alloc / pbuf_free every time a message needs sending using PBUF_RAM.  It appears to  work fine, but I'm worried it will lead to memory fragmentation nastiness after it's been running for a long time. Should I be worried?

Also, is it true that PBUF_POOL is for receiving messages *only*, not for sending?

Answer (score 0):

PBUF_POOL is for RX only, the idea is to separate the memory pool for received packets and buffered TX segments. See [PBUF_POOL define](http://git.savannah.nongnu.org/cgit/lwip.git/tree/src/include/lwip/pbuf.h) for documentation

In terms of PBUF_RAM and fragmentation in the memory heap, there are a number of configurations which determine how the heap is implemented, which may affect fragmentation. So you'll want to understand your configuration.

Heap could be implemented by standard C library malloc, a series of various fixed sized pools, or a single static array. If using the latter, plug_holes() is called from mem_free() which should handle fragments.  See [mem.c](http://git.savannah.nongnu.org/cgit/lwip.git/tree/src/core/mem.c)